# delphi xe - twebbrowser change hyperlinks's title font

Tags: delphi, tooltip, delphi-xe, twebbrowser

In DELPHI TWEBBROWSER hyperlinks' title attribute values are shown as hints using the Windows system font for tooltips.

Is there any way to set custom fonts for hyperlinks' tooltips in HTML?

Comment: Definitely not using HTML or any standardised CSS. Most likely not at all using HTML+CSS. (Well, of course you could implement the hints entirely using HTML+CSS.)

Comment: I need to change only the font for tooltips of hyperlinks. And how it can be implemented using HTML+CSS ? I found nothing about it.

Comment: I found source codes for tooltips (pure CSS tooltips at https://github.com/freqdec/Pure-CSS-Tooltips/blob/master/index.html for example), but no one works in Delphi's TWebbrowser.